# Google Trends - determine if embedded code is empty

Tags: javascript, php, iframe, google-trends

I use code from google trends

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//www.google.com/trends/embed.js?hl=ru&cat=0-19&q=999999999&cmpt=q&tz=Etc/GMT-4&tz=Etc/GMT-4&content=1&cid=TIMESERIES_GRAPH_0&export=5&w=500&h=330"></script>
```

But how can I determine if embedded code is empty? For example for `q=40404040404040` :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//www.google.com/trends/embed.js?hl=ru&cat=0-19&q=999999999&cmpt=q&tz=Etc/GMT-4&tz=Etc/GMT-4&content=1&cid=TIMESERIES_GRAPH_0&export=5&w=500&h=330"></script>
```

Google just give empty body iframe, which takes place on a page and show nothing.

How can I determine if this embedded code is empty and show something like 'no trends' or not show this empty iframe at all?